# Aggregating and calculating in Ordereddict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools, ordereddictionary

Have a Ordereddict "d" looking like that:

```
[OrderedDict([
              ('id', '1'),
              ('date', '20170101'),
              ('quantity', '10')]),
 OrderedDict([
              ('id', '2'),
              ('date', '20170102'),
              ('quantity', '3')]),
 OrderedDict([
              ('id', '3'),
              ('date', '20170102'),
              ('quantity', '1')])]
```

I'm trying to do the group by 'date' and calculating the sum of quantity and display these two columns 'date' and 'sum_quantity'. How can I do that not using pandas groupby options?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "display these two columns", print them out? Could you show your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is pure python approach, This is just an example to give you a hint. If you want in pure python you can use this.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import itertools
data=[OrderedDict([
              ('id', '1'),
              ('date', '20170101'),
              ('quantity', '10')]),
 OrderedDict([
              ('id', '2'),
              ('date', '20170102'),
              ('quantity', '3')]),
 OrderedDict([
              ('id', '3'),
              ('date', '20170102'),
              ('quantity', '1')])]



def get_quantity(ord_dict):
    new_ = []
    for g in [list(i) for j, i in itertools.groupby(ord_dict, lambda x: x['date'])]:
        if len(g) > 1:
            sub_dict={}
            temp = []
            date = []
            for i in g:
                temp.append(int(i['quantity']))
                date.append(i['date'])
            sub_dict['date'] = date[0]
            sub_dict['sum_quantity'] = sum(temp)
            new_.append(sub_dict)


        else:
            for i in g:
                sub_dict={}
                sub_dict['date']=i['date']
                sub_dict['sum_quantity']=i['quantity']
                new_.append(sub_dict)

    return new_
print(get_quantity(data))
```

output:

```
[{'date': '20170101', 'sum_quantity': '10'}, {'date': '20170102', 'sum_quantity': 4}]
```

Comment: Why ignore `'date', '20170101'`?

Comment: He said he wanted to show only grouped dates sum. as he said " these two columns 'date' and 'sum_quantity'"

Comment: That's not how I would parse his English.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski please correct me if I got it wrong.

Comment: Yes, the idea was to have aggregations for all of the dates in the list

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to do the group by 'date' and calculating the sum of quantity and display these two columns 'date' and 'sum_quantity'

This code puts the dates as keys and then the value is the sum of quantity. The output is a bit of a guess until you show an example of your desired output.

```
In[2]: from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict
  ...: 
  ...: 
  ...: def solution(data):
  ...:     result = defaultdict(int)
  ...:     for od in data:
  ...:         result[od['date']] += int(od['quantity'])
  ...:     return result
  ...: 
In[3]: data = [
  ...:     OrderedDict([
  ...:         ('id', '1'),
  ...:         ('date', '20170101'),
  ...:         ('quantity', '10')]),
  ...:     OrderedDict([
  ...:         ('id', '2'),
  ...:         ('date', '20170102'),
  ...:         ('quantity', '3')]),
  ...:     OrderedDict([
  ...:         ('id', '3'),
  ...:         ('date', '20170102'),
  ...:         ('quantity', '1')])
  ...: ]
In[4]: grouped = solution(data)
In[5]: grouped
Out[5]: defaultdict(int, {'20170101': 10, '20170102': 4})
In[6]: print('{:>8}\tSum Quantity'.format('Date'))
  ...: for k, v in grouped.items():
  ...:     print('{}\t{:>12}'.format(k, v))
  ...: 
    Date    Sum Quantity
20170101              10
20170102               4
```

Answer (score 0):

**Given**

```
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict


lst = [
    OrderedDict([
              ("id", "1"),
              ("date", "20170101"),
              ("quantity", "10")]),
    OrderedDict([
              ("id", "2"),
              ("date", "20170102"),
              ("quantity", "3")]),
    OrderedDict([
              ("id", "3"),
              ("date", "20170102"),
              ("quantity", "1")])
]
```

Borrowing from [`more_itertools.map_reduce`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.map_reduce) recipe:

```
def map_reduce(iterable, keyfunc, valuefunc=None, reducefunc=None):
    valuefunc = (lambda x: x) if (valuefunc is None) else valuefunc

    ret = defaultdict(list)
    for item in iterable:
        key = keyfunc(item)
        value = valuefunc(item)
        ret[key].append(value)

    if reducefunc is not None:
        for key, value_list in ret.items():
            ret[key] = reducefunc(value_list)

    ret.default_factory = None
    return ret
```

**Code**

`map_reduce` builds a `defaultdict` with customizable keys and values.  The reducing function is applied to the final list of values.

```
kfunc = lambda d: d["date"]
vfunc = lambda d: int(d["quantity"])
rfunc = lambda lst_: sum(lst_) 
agg = map_reduce(lst, keyfunc=kfunc, valuefunc=vfunc, reducefunc=rfunc)
agg
# defaultdict(None, {'20170101': 10, '20170102': 4})
```

We use a list comprehension for the final result.

```
[{"date": k, "sum_quantity": v} for k, v in agg.items()]
# [{'date': '20170101', 'sum_quantity': 10}, {'date': '20170102', 'sum_quantity': 4}]
```